# Django QueryDict gets merged GET parameters

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django 1.9, Python 3.5.1.

I have Select2 input in my form, that stores its data in `filter_tags` param.
I can see something like this in server log:

```
[...] "GET /events?t_from=A&t_to=B&filter_tags=accumsan&filter_tags=alpha&filter_tags=aenean HTTP/1.1" 200 12290
```

But when I try to access QueryDict at `request.GET` in my view I see that it doesn't have list of three values, but instead only has one last value:

```
<QueryDict: {'t_from': ['A'], 'filter_tags': ['aenean'], 't_to': ['B']}>
```

And so `request.GET.getlist('filter_tags')` only last item.

I start Django with `manage.py runserver` and don't use any kind of web server in front of it (e.g. nginx, apache). I've tried to disable every middleware there is, but that didn't help. I also don't manipulate request.GET in any way, basically my view doesn't do anything with it:

```
def my_view(request):
    logging.warning(request.GET)
    ...
```

How do I get all my `filter_tags`?

**UPD**
Manually creating QueryDict seems to work just fine:

```
q = QueryDict('t_from=A&t_to=B&filter_tags=ac&filter_tags=accumsan')
<QueryDict: {'t_from': ['A'], 't_to': ['B'], 'filter_tags': ['ac', 'accumsan']}>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [QueryDict.lists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists) ?

Comment: What is the output of `request.META['QUERY_STRING']`?

Comment: `request.GET.lists()` is `<dict_itemiterator object at 0x1021178b8>`, not sure how to inspect it yet.

`QUERY_STRING` is `t_from=A&t_to=B&filter_tags=aenean`

Comment: This shouldn't happen, and for me it doesn't. From `request.GET.getlist('filter_tags')` I get `['accumsan', 'alpha', 'aenean']`. What exact Django version are you on (patch version number)? What distribution? Could you post the exact contents of your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`? Did you try restarting your `runserver` process? If none of this helps, could you try to make the smallest complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was explicitly using `{{ request.GET.filter_tags }}` in my JS code I totally forgot about :( Fixed it and everything runs smooth now.

Jon Clements, Burhan Khalid, marcelm, thanks guys!